# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

quiero enviar un request all en laravel por un procedmiento almacenado pero me da error alguna idea de como hacerlo

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $data = DB::select('call InsertarUsuario(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',$request->all());
    }
```

me tira el siguiente error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: call InsertarUsuario(Camilo, Pepe, prueba@hotmail.com, 2, ENABLE)) in file C:\laragon\www\innovar2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 671

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

envio 5 elementos

Comment: si yo puedo extraer los valores del request y meterlos en el procedimento pero queria hacer en una linea para que el codigo fuera limpio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacer esto:

```
$request->all();
```

Nos estaría mandando una estructura como la siguiente:

```
{"_token":"dvj6GNzG5g0FygBlvT1ByPAoXvYmEuY9aU8CfBgB","clave":"valor","clave":"valor"}
```

Entonces tendrías que hacerlo así:

- En lugar de pasar como segundo argumento el `$request->all()` pasamos un array
- El array para tu caso tendrá 5 posiciones, donde cada una indicará a que clave debe acceder `$request->`

Entonces puede quedar de este modo:

```
DB::select('call InsertarUsuario(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$request->clave1, $request->clave2, $request->clave3, $request->clave4, $request->clave5]);
```

> Donde las denominadas claves del 1 al 5 serán las que tengas que cambiar de nombre de acuerdo con los valores que tu esperas

Comment: ´Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031´ me salio esto

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar revisa la edición

Answer (score 0):

El error indicado (2031) indica que algunos parametros no se han pasado a la funcion.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/client-error-reference.html#error_cr_params_not_bound

Puede ser que Falta agregar alguno de los parametros esperados de `InsertarUsuario()` o no se han pasado los valores de todos los parametros en `?` (en este caso 5) .
Revisa la definicion de la funcion y que valores esta generando la llamada a `$request->all()` (es un array de 5 elementos?).